# I have learnt how to code SQL in Oracle but need help converting it to work in MYSQL version 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

This is the dropping of the tables, I think you need to put if exists after the table names

```
    drop table active_questions;
    drop table question;
    drop table questionaire;
    drop table question_status;
    drop table scrum_team;
    drop table acc_user;
    drop table login;
```

Then this is where I need to create the tables:

```
    create table login
        (login_id Number(15) not null primary key,
        password varchar2(20) not null);

    create table acc_user
        (acc_user_id Number(15) not null primary key,
        surname varchar2(20) not null,
        firstname varchar2(20) not null,
        login_id Number(15) not null references login(login_id));

    create table scrum_team
        (scrum_id Number(15) not null primary key,
         acc_user_id Number(15) not null references acc_user(acc_user_id));

    create table question_status
        (status_id Number(15) not null primary key,
         status_desc varchar2(50) not null);

    create table questionaire
        (questionaire_id Number(15) not null primary key,
         status_id number(15) not null references question_status(status_id));

    create table question
        (question_id Number(15) not null primary key,
         question varchar2(200) not null);

    create table active_questions
        (active_ques_id Number(15) not null primary key,
         question_id Number(15) not null references question(question_id),
         questionaire_id number(15) not null references questionaire(questionaire_id)
        );




            commit;
```

This is the code I need to change across

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What would the code be in order to get it to work in MYSQL version 5.6, because I keep getting errors whenever I try to do the foreign keys for tables, sorry about not making it clear!

Comment: edit your question to include this information that you are converting from Orcale to MYSQL and show the error in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such types as number and varchar2 in mysql try changing them to integer an varchar (nd you need not specify the integer length). The drop table syntax is drop table if exists tablename;